# Why does this code gives segmentation fault with some inputs?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
//difference of two diagonals of a N x N matrix
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int N, j, i,k,l;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    int array[N-1][N-1], sum1=0, sum2=0, sum=0;
    for(i=0;i<N; i++)
        {
        for(j=0; j<N; j++)
            {
            scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(k = 0; k<N; k++){
        sum1 += array[k][k];
    }
    for(l=0; l<N; l++){
        sum2 += array[N-1-l][l];
    }
    sum = abs(sum1 - sum2);
    printf("%d",sum);   
    return 0;
}
```

The above code generates segmentation fault for some inputs. The program calculates absolute difference between the summation of all the values in the two main diagonal.

Comment: What inputs exaclty? `0`? non-numeric input?

Comment: When you declare your array, your dimensions are off by one.  You need an NxN array (highest indices will be (N-1) and (N-1)).

Comment: try declaring array of size [N][N]

Comment: C arrays start with 0 index, so an array[N][N] will have its last element in array[N-1][N-1]. You are declarating an array of N-1xN-1 and accessing the position array[N-1][N-1], when the last element is at array[N-2][N-2]. This causes undefined behavior and, in some cases, SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem, I think, is that you're declaring your array of size `N - 1` × `N - 1`, but then filling in `N` elements.  Do try declaring it `N`×`N`.

Comment: That is not the main problem. There is no check for `N == 0`, and there is no check for `scanf()` success.

Comment: @iharob, that is the main problem if not the only problem.

Comment: @iharob if `N == 0` the program won't execute anything more than `0 - 0`.

Comment: The OP claims that it happens on some of the input.

Comment: But that doesn't really tell us anything.

Comment: @LuizEduardoF. `if (N == 0)` then `int array[-1][-1];` follows. Also, if the input is invalid the code will invoke undefined behavior for many reasons. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31172947/1983495).

Answer (score 1):

You declared array `array` as having `N-1` rows and `N-1` columns

```
int array[N-1][N-1], /*...*/;
```

So the valid range of indices for rows and columns of the array is `[0, N-2]`

However in the loops of the program you are trying to access elements of the array with indices `N-1`. For example

```
for(i=0;i<N; i++)
    {
    for(j=0; j<N; j++)
        {
        scanf("%d",&array[i][j]);
    }
}
```

that is you are trying to access memory beyond the array and as result the program has undefined behaviour.

Simply write the declaration of the array like

```
int array[N][N], /*...*/;
```

Take into account that the sizes of the array shall be positive values.

Also you may remove headers

```
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
```

because no declaration from the headers is used in the program.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, invalid input will cause Undefined Behavior.

You need to ensure that the input is valid, for that you can check `scanf()`'s return value, like this

```
if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1)
    return -1;
```

Then you need to ensure that `N > 0`, because you allocate space for `N - 1` items, so

```
if (N <= 1) /* this also prevents `int array[0][0];' */
    return -1;
```

should be added.

Then you have to fix your loops, you allocate space for `N - 1` items but you do `N` iterations from `0` to `N - 1`, `N - 1` is an invalid index if you have only allocated `N - 1` elements, you need to do one of two things

1. Fix the loop

   ```
   for (int i = 0 ; i < N - 1 ; ++i) /* ... etc. */
   ```
2. Allocate space for `N` elements,

   ```
   int array[N][N];
   ```

   in this case you should change the check on `N`, to

   ```
   if (N < 1)
       return -1;
   ```

The reason why different input triggers different behavior, is because accessing an array beyond it's limits causes **undefined behavior**. So it will sometimes work some other times it will cause a *segmentation fault* and even some other times something else because it's *undefined*.

But there is yet another source of undefined behavrior that also depends on input and it's the way you used `scanf()`. If you type `asdasd` then `N` will be uninitialized when you declare your `array` variable, hence undefined behavior will happen too.